# wpdb->prepare function remove single quote for %s in SQL statment

Tags: mysql, sql, wpdb

I am using the below wpdb->prepare function in a sql statement.  I am passing in several variables some field names and some values.  When I try to use the %s for the field name it puts single quotes around it.  How can I prevent the single quotes around the field name?  The  sql statement will not execute with the single quotes?

`$query = $wpdb->prepare("SELECT DISTINCT wp_geo.%s, wp_geo.$field2 
FROM wp_geo
WHERE wp_geo.$field3=%s",$field1, $typevalue);`

Output with single quotes around 'county_short' field name:

`SELECT DISTINCT wp_geo.'county_short', wp_geo.county_slug FROM wp_geo WHERE wp_geo.type='trailers'`

Comment: yes, for example, how can I avoid quotes on WHERE `ID` IN ('26975,27015,27016,27017,27018') ? $wpdb->prepare wraps my ids with quotes !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot suppress the quotes in $wpdb. Run [`mysqli_real_escape_string()`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.real-escape-string.php) in *your* script on these variables.

Answer (score 7):

You can use %1s which excludes single quotes wrapper.
By using %1s, you will note that the string won't be having single quotes and you will get the values directly as needed.

```
$query = $wpdb->prepare("
              SELECT DISTINCT wp_geo.%1s, wp_geo.%1s
              FROM wp_geo
              WHERE wp_geo.%1s = %1s",
              $field1, 
              $field2, 
              $field3, 
              $typevalue
         );
```

**Note:** Here, the sequence should follow for %1s and the variable you are providing after the query.

Answer (score 4):

You can't use prepare() on column names, only on values.

Comment: +1, the `%s` is intended as a placeholder for string variables only. If the column name is unknown (though rarely is) whitelist it.